# Get record where a value is unique in the whole table/column

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am looking to get the row where a value is unique in the whole column:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value 1 | value 2 | value 3 |
| value 1 | value 2 | value 3 |
| value a | value b | value c |
| value a | **value x** | value c |
| value 1 | value b | value c |

Tried with:

```
SELECT col2,  COUNT(col2) 
FROM the_table
WHERE col3='value c' 
GROUP BY col2 
HAVING COUNT(col2) = 1 
ORDER BY COUNT(col2);
```

but I`m getting only the value not the whole row.

Answer (score 2):

Use analytic function

Here is the idea

```
select 
 tab.*,
 count(*) over (partition by col2) cnt_col2
from tab
where col3 = 'c'

col1|col2|col3|cnt_col2|
----+----+----+--------+
a   |b   |c   |       2|
q   |b   |c   |       2|
a   |x   |c   |       1|
```

So simple add an other query an filter only row(s) with `cnt_col2 = 1`.

Here the general solution to find unique value of `col2` within any column `col3` (with sample data in CTO)

```
with tab as (
select * from (values
('1', '2','3'),
('1', '2','3'),
('1', '1','3'),
('1', '3','3'),
('a', 'b','c'),
('a', 'x','c'),
('q', 'b','c')
) tab(col1, col2,col3)
), tab2 as (
select 
 tab.*,
 count(*) over (partition by col3, col2) cnt_col32
from tab)
select * from tab2
where cnt_col32 = 1

col1|col2|col3|cnt_col32|
----+----+----+---------+
1   |1   |3   |        1|
1   |3   |3   |        1|
a   |x   |c   |        1|
```